# User can't see GAL and I can't find why

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

we are in the middle of a exchange 2003 to 2010 conversion and I have one user on the new server that isn't able to see the GAL but is listed inside it.  I've looked over the permissions and can't see anything missing, he has open address list and list contents.  Are there other permissions I need to look at or anything I should know that could have happened while we are in the middle of the conversion?  This specific user was created on the new 2010 server, so he wasn't moved.  I would even appreciate troubleshooting steps or testing programs at this point!

Comment: Have any other users been created on the 2010 server and/or can you create a test user?  Does the same problem apply to those other new accounts?

Comment: Is this still an issue or were you able to resolve it? If resolved, add an answer so the community can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer was stop using exchange and move to Google Workspace.